# Rails app using Mysql how to deploy with heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

How to deploy a Rails app using Mysql on heroku?

I find out that my app did not need Amazon RDS (Too expensive for a small app).

Here is my answer how to use Amazon RDS

[Heroku help deploying Rails app that uses Mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362288/heroku-help-deploying-rails-app-that-uses-mysql-database)

Comment: This user very recently asked the same question: [Heroku help deploying Rails app that uses Mysql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362288/heroku-help-deploying-rails-app-that-uses-mysql-database)

Comment: Yes I have tried. I have pushed my app to heroku and added Amazon RDS. But I cant connect to the database.  See my steps here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362288/heroku-help-deploying-rails-app-that-uses-mysql-database

Comment: http://heroku.com/ - create -> deploy -> work -- everything is written there, no?

Comment: no. Should I use Amazon RDS for a Mysql database?

Comment: Heroku uses PostgreSQL I need to use MySql because I have much of MySql data I need to push

Comment: I get the same error as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969272/trouble-connecting-heroku-app-with-amazon-rds-instance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you do a `heroku db:push` from your MySql data, it'll automatically get pushed into the heorku PostgreSQL database structure.

You can then do db:pulls and pull back into mysql. [Taps](http://adam.heroku.com/past/2009/2/11/taps_for_easy_database_transfers/) provides this database magic.

It's really great -- I'd try it out first before trying to get RDS working.

Comment: I have got the RDS to work and have pushed my database to RDS. But my app still crashes here is my log http://pastie.org/1690168

Comment: My answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362288/heroku-help-deploying-rails-app-that-uses-mysql-database

Comment: This answer may need to be updated. Running `heroku db:push` gives the error `db:push is not a heroku command.`

Answer (score 22):

Include mysql2 gem in your gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

Now, your choice can be: https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb add-ons. You can get upto 5mb free storage but you need to fill your credit card information for accessing it.

Steps for using clearDB add-ons are:

````
# add cleardb add-ons to your app
$ heroku addons:add cleardb:ignite
-----> Adding cleardb to sharp-mountain-4005... done, v18 (free)


# retrieve your database URL:
$ heroku config | grep CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL => mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true


# copy CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL config variable and set it to your DATABASE_URL config variable
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'
Adding config vars:
DATABASE_URL => mysql2://adffd...b?reconnect=true
Restarting app... done, v61.

# NOTE: since we are using ```mysql2``` in our gemfile so replace mysql:// scheme in the CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL to mysql2://
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql2://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'
$ heroku config:set CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL='mysql2://adffdadf2341:adf4234@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_db?reconnect=true'
````

Please follow: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb for more information

Hope that can help you.