# Unable to connect to MySQL DB on Production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm thinking that I've done up the `database.yml` file improperly. The file is as follows:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: blog_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: blog_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: ENV['CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL']
  username: ENV['CLEARDB_DATABASE_USERNAME']
  password: ENV['CLEARDB_DATABASE_PASSWORDs']
```

When I run `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get:

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.8056
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have ClearDB installed with mysql2.

Comment: Check your sock file.Is it present?

Comment: How do I check that on Heroku?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310967/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-tmp-mysql-sock

Comment: please see here for using mysql on heroku...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362903/rails-app-using-mysql-how-to-deploy-with-heroku

Comment: @LHH That is already all done. CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL is `mysql2://` and not `mysql://`. ClearDB is already installed on Heroku and PostgreSQL uninstalled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is in the environment variable. Renaming `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL` to `DATABASE_URL` solved the problem.

Renaming occurred in the heroku config and in the database.yml.